# PySide / Qt : Too many arguments to connect a signal to a slot?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals, pyside

I'm trying to connect a custom signal (in a `TCP` client class) to a method that updates a log with the data sent by the server and whatnot.

Here's the declaration of the `TCP` client class:

```
class CarSocket(QObject):
    logSignal = Signal(str, str)
    ...
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(CarSocket, self).__init__()
        ...
```

And the method I'm trying to connect to `logSignal` :

```
def addToLog(self, text, mode='NORMAL'):
    if mode == 'RAW':
        toAdd = text
    else:
        toAdd = "<p>{}</p> \n <hr> \n".format(text)
    self.log.logEdit.append(toAdd)
```

So, I write this line when initializing my application:

```
self.carSocket.logSignal.connect(self.addToLog)
```

And I get a really weird bug when I execute it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/workspace/autonomee/main.py", line 286, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "/home/ahmed/workspace/autonomee/main.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.carSocket.logSignal.connect(self.addToLog)
TypeError: connect() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Anyone can help ?

It must be noted that I already succesfuly connected a custom signal on another class (with an int, connected to a method of the class itself) and that I have no problems connecting 'default' signals with default slots (like `self.button.clicked.connect(self.edit.clear)` or something similar)

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine for me, both with PySide and PyQt4. Are you updated to the latest version of PySide?

BTW, I used [this](http://pastebin.com/JUEEDM5f) as a crude example to test it, is it basically correct?

Comment: Your examples works :/ (and as I said I'm already working with another custom signal, on another class, that works perfectly). I also have the latest version of PySide : 1.1.2

Comment: The full source code (minus the line connecting the signal) can be found on: https://github.com/halflings/autonomee (the signal connection should be done on `main.py` ; and the `CarSocket` class is in `carsocket.py`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just had this problem with my own code, and wanted to contribute what I (think) is the answer. You also have a function called "connect" in your CarSocket class. Try renaming that function and see what happens.

In my case one of my classes that was emitting the signal also had a "connect" function, and renaming it fixed the problem. It shouldn't have caused a problem since you call connect from the Signal() type itself, but there seems to be problems.

Comment: It's weird that that helps.

Comment: Ah, in my case it's because my class inherited `QObject`, which also has a connect method.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when I am trying to run your program. It looks really weird. I've found only one mention about that [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyside/54BwODui3bw/divUXjpPMUUJ) but no solution. One thing I can suggest you is old-style `connect` still works correctly:

```
self.connect(self.carSocket, SIGNAL("logSignal(str, str)"), self, SLOT("addToLog(str, str)"))
```

Possible it's bug of PySide. In comments people said that they don't have problem with PySide 1.1.2. I've this version too and Qt of version 4.8.4.

Comment: I tried it and even if it doesn't make the program bug, it doesn't do anything (nothing happens when I emit a signal)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap signal in a QObject:

```
class CarSocketSignal(QObject):
    logSignal = Signal(str, str)

class CarSocket(QObject):
    cslogSignal = CarSocketSignal()
...
def __init__(self, ...):
    super(CarSocket, self).__init__()
    ...
```

This call would then be:

```
self.carSocket.cslogSignal.logSignal.connect(self.addToLog)
```

This should work...